# haskell wreq param list

Tags: http, haskell, url, wreq

In the excellent `wreq` Haskell library it is easy to add one or more query parameters to an URL:

`opts = defaults & param "key" .~ ["value"]`

however what I'm struggling to do is adding a *list* of parameters at a time:

`params = [("key1", "value1"), ("key2", "value2"), ("key3", "value3")]`

I know that there is function `params` but I could not find any example on how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `param <key>` and `params` are lenses:

```
param  :: Text -> Lens' Options [Text] 
params ::         Lens' Options [(Text, Text)]
```

Without going too much into details, you can think of a lens focusing something, e.g. `param "foo"` focuses on some `[Text]` in `Options` that belong to the parameter `foo` (*). You can then change/query/manipulate those values with the correct function (see the [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package).

You've already used `(.~)` to replace the current values, and you can use it again with `params`:

```
default & params .~ [("key1", "value1"), ("key2", "value2"), ("key3", "value3")]
```

You can think of `(.~)` in this context as

```
(.~) :: Lens' a b -> b -> a -> a
-- concrete:
(.~) :: Lens' Options [(Text, Text)] -> [(Text, Text)] -> Options -> Options
```

<sub>(*) That's not 100% true, since lenses allow you to do all kinds of stuff, but good enough for this context.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much Zeta, who would have thought it would be so simple! The usual me, trying to overcomplicate easy things -_- !

Comment: @SimoneTrubian You're welcome. If this answer satisfies you, make sure [to accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/191939), otherwise it will stay as "unanswered" in several filters.